# json array to class

Tags: .net, vb.net, json, restsharp, arrays

**i have this json array response:**

```
    [
  {
    "status": "active",
    "url": "https:\/\/ikiosk.podio.com\/dev\/apps\/myusers",
    "url_label": "myusers",
    "space_id": 550628,
    "link_add": "https:\/\/ikiosk.podio.com\/dev\/apps\/2304568\/items\/new",
    "app_id": 2304568,
    "date_field": false,
    "link": "https:\/\/ikiosk.podio.com\/dev\/apps\/myusers",
    "config": {
      "allow_edit": true,
      "description": "",
      "item_name": "myusers",
      "type": "standard",
      "icon_id": 251,
      "allow_create": true,
      "usage": "",
      "icon": "251.png",
      "external_id": null,
      "name": "myusers"
    },
    "url_add": "https:\/\/ikiosk.podio.com\/dev\/apps\/2304568\/items\/new"
  },
  {
    "status": "active",
    "url": "https:\/\/ikiosk.podio.com\/dev\/apps\/requests",
    "url_label": "requests",
    "space_id": 550628,
    "link_add": "https:\/\/ikiosk.podio.com\/dev\/apps\/2299738\/items\/new",
    "app_id": 2299738,
    "date_field": true,
    "link": "https:\/\/ikiosk.podio.com\/dev\/apps\/requests",
    "config": {
      "allow_edit": true,
      "description": "",
      "item_name": "request",
      "type": "standard",
      "icon_id": 251,
      "allow_create": true,
      "usage": "",
      "icon": "251.png",
      "external_id": null,
      "name": "Requests"
    },
    "url_add": "https:\/\/ikiosk.podio.com\/dev\/apps\/2299738\/items\/new"
  }
]
```

**And here the classes:**

```
Public Class GetAllApps
    Public pApplication As PodioApplication
End Class


Public Class PodioApplication
    Public status As String
End Class
```

**My code here:**

```
Dim client As New RestClient()
client.BaseUrl = "https://api.podio.com/"

Dim request As New RestRequest()
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
request = New RestRequest()
request.Method = Method.[GET]
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
request.AddParameter("oauth_token", access_token)
request.Resource = "/app/v2//"

Dim resp = client.Execute(Of List(Of GetAllApps))(request)  
RichTextBox1.Text = resp.Content

Dim pApps As List(Of PodioApplication) = resp.Data.[Select](Function(c) c.pApplication).ToList()
MsgBox(pApps.Count)

For Each p As PodioApplication In pApps
   MsgBox(p.status)
Next
```

the json array that i wrote before is the result of resp.Content.
At line of code MsgBox(pApps.Count) I take the correct number (in this scenario is 2).
But in the for each loop I take the exception error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Is there any problem with my implementation, something missing?

Comment: Have you fired this up in the debugger? My guess is your deserialisation code (that you didn't include in your question) is broken and gives you an array with 2 `null`s in it. (Or whatever VB people call `null`.)

Comment: I have added all lines of code that I wrote for that. Check it please.

Comment: I can't find `RestClient` or `RestRequest` in MSDN, what library are they from. Also, have you checked in the debugger to see what's actually in `pApps`? (I'm assuming you already checked if your JSON response is coming in right with the `RichTextBox1.Text` line.)

Comment: Seems you've found a solution, but my guess is that your wrapper class `GetAllApps` might be useless. Try changing the call to `client.Execute(Of List(Of PodioApplication))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally,

I made it simple:

```
Dim client As New RestClient()
        client.BaseUrl = "https://api.podio.com/"
        Dim request As New RestRequest()
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
        request = New RestRequest()
        request.Method = Method.[GET]
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
        request.AddParameter("oauth_token", access_token)
        request.Resource = "/app/v2//"
        Dim response = client.Execute(request)
        Dim ser As New JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim pApps As List(Of PodioApplication) = ser.Deserialize(Of List(Of PodioApplication))(response.Content)
```

Now the pApps have the correct data from the response.